# smartctl megaraid,N ( how to find the right value for N ? )

Tags: linux, rhel, disk, fdisk, smartctl

we run the smartctl on sdb disk

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Smartctl open device: /dev/sdb failed: DELL or MegaRaid controller, please try adding '-d megaraid,N'
```

according to the output from  smartctl we change it to

```
 smartctl -a -d megaraid,0 /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               TOSHIBA
Product:              MG04SCA20ENY
.
.
```

and I set the - 0 , according to the first bus ( from smartctl  --scan )

```
smartctl  --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,0 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_00], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,12 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_12], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,13 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_13], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,14 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_14], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,16 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_16], SCSI device
```

but I am not sure if this value "0" is the right value

am I right here ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "right" value. If you want to identify which disk is attached to which megaraid port, look at the vendor/productid value. If there's no label on your physical disk, attach it somewhere else to find out which disk is which (or remove all other disks).

Comment: what I mean is that - for example lets take the - megaraid,0 , this include the value - 0 , so I took it for N

Comment: Yes, you can use 0, or 12, or 13, or 14, or 16 for N. If your scan output isn't complete, possibly even more numbers. And you already tried with 0, and it worked. So try the others, too. How many harddisks have you connected to this controller?

Comment: I accept this , so you can post an answer and I will vote for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use 0, or 12, or 13, or 14, or 16 for N.

If your scan output isn't complete, possibly even more numbers.

And you already tried with 0, and it worked. So try the others, too.

Comment: How does one find the *right* value reliably?

Comment: `smartctl --scan` will show possible values. The DID column in `storcli /call /eall /sall show` also seems to match.

Comment: For the renamed CLI: `perccli /call /eall /sall show`

Answer (score 1):

The N value in `megaraid,N` is the number of the physical disk. If you 4 disks, they will be numbered 0-3, as shown by the output of `smartctl --scan`.

Comment: "If you 4 disks, they will be numbered 0-3"
This is wrong as you can see in the question text. For me device ids start at 32 and go up to 55. It seems to be the "DID" meaning Device ID.