# Smartd reports error on device in hardware raid but smartctl cannot see it

Tags: debian, raid, smartctl

First time I'm using hardware RAID (I only knew soft raid).

I'm running Debian 9.13.

Smartd daemon reports the following error :

```
Device: /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_04] [SAT], 5 Offline uncorrectable sectors

Device info:
HGST HUS726T6TALE6L4, S/N:V8GH9HUR, WWN:5-000cca-098c6f544, FW:VKGNW460, 6.00 TB
```

But I don't see this device :

```
$ ls -l /dev/bus/0
ls: cannot access '/dev/bus/0': No such file or directory
```

And I can't run smartctl on it :

```
$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/bus/0
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.9.0-14-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/bus/0: Unable to detect device type
Please specify device type with the -d option.

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary
```

All I can see with fdisk are the disk resulting from the hardware RAID :

```
$ sudo fdisk -l | grep '^Disk /'
Disk /dev/sda: 931 GiB, 999653638144 bytes, 1952448512 sectors
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.4 TiB, 18001818550272 bytes, 35159801856 sectors
```

Any idea how I can access info on the faulty disk?

Regards

Santiago

Comment: Possible duplicate of [smartctl megaraid,N ( how to find the right value for N ? )](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/485463/100397)

Comment: Thanks! That helped